# Reply Button Causing Crash

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am making a 4Chanesque reply View Controller. My plan is to allow users to write replies in a textView. The reply button should then take their text and add it to an array of strings called "comment" in the Post class. The tableView will then display their comment at the bottom of the comment section for that post.

Here is my View Controller for Comments:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

class MainTextView: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var titleText: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var mainText: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var commentPlaceHolder: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var newCommentLabel: UITextView!
weak var delegate:NewPostVCDelegate?

@IBAction func reply(_ sender: UIButton) {

// Firebase code here
    let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoId()

    let postObject = [
        "comment": newCommentLabel.text,
        "timestamp": [".sv": "timestamp"]
        ] as [String : Any]

    postRef.setValue(postObject, withCompletionBlock: { error, ref in
        if error == nil {
            self.delegate!.didUploadPost(withID: ref.key!)
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }  else {
            // Handle error

        }
    })
    newCommentLabel.text = String()
    commentPlaceHolder.isHidden = false
}
var post: Post?
```

For Reference, here is my Post class

```
import Foundation

class Post {
var id:String
var title: String
var text:String
var createdAt:Date
var comment: [String] = []

init(id: String, title: String,text:String,  timestamp:Double, comment: [String] = []) {
    self.id = id
    self.title = title
    self.text = text
    self.createdAt = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp / 1000)




}
static func parse(_ key:String, data:[String:Any]) -> Post? {
    if let title = data["text"] as? String,
        let text = data["title"] as? String,
        let timestamp = data["timestamp"] as? Double {
        return Post(id: key, title: title,  text: text, timestamp:timestamp, comment: [])
        }


    return nil
    }
}
```

And the NewPostVCDelegate is declared in my NewPostViewController as such:

```
protocol NewPostVCDelegate: class {
func didUploadPost(withID id:String)
  }
```

I am wondering if the delegate is causing me to try to make a new post when I really just want to add a comment to an existing post. I am not sure how to rectify this issue programatically. Currently, I am getting a crash message when I press the reply button. It reads: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". This error message red highlights the line: "self.delegate!.didUploadPost(withID: ref.key!)".  Thank you for your help.

Comment: what the crash and where it points

Comment: If there is a crash, you might have an error message in console? Which is...? Also, did you point out which line is causing the crash? I see a few force unwrap (use of "!"), are they the culprits? Which one?

Comment: Edited to add information about the error message on the bottom. Thank you for reminding me!

Comment: note: var delegate:NewPostVCDelegate? should be weak, otherwise it can cause memory leak

Comment: where the debugger points , what line of code has a red mark on it when the crash happens

Comment: Put a break point at the crashed line, check the debugger window to see if `ref` and `ref.key` or `delegate` have value or not

Comment: I added the line. I also made the protocol a class and made it a weak var.

Comment: can you do `print(delegate!)` top of `viewDidLoad` and see if crashes ?

Comment: This caused error:  Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. Upon opening the view

Comment: How do you present `MainTextView` ??

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
        
        if let destination = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"MainTextView") as? MainTextView {
            destination.post = (posts[indexPath.row])
            navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
            
   
        }
    
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the crash is here

```
self.delegate!.didUploadPost(withID: ref.key!)
```

Your delegate is `nil` , you need to set it here `destination.delegate = self`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true) 
      if let destination = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"MainTextView") as? MainTextView {
          destination.post = posts[indexPath.row]  
          destination.delegate = self
          navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true) 
     }
 }
```